# Can only access HTTPS secure sites at a router level

Tags: networking, router, http, https

I've got an ASUS router running `DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) giga`. Sometime in the last week I have not been able to access remote sites through standard HTTP (port 80). HTTPS on port 443 works without issues. A complicating factor is that I am configuring and troubleshooting remotely - I am away from home for the summer and do not have physical access to the router. I am configuring the router via telnet, that telnet session itself within an remote SSH session into my server. I would have reset my router already, but I rely on a cloned MAC address for a WAN connection, and resetting that would prevent me from connecting away from home entirely.

I should also note that this issue did not appear after I re-configured something - I'm almost positive it was something that happened overnight. It is possible I had done something unintentionally, though. Not sure what it could have been.

These commands are run logged in as root, directly on the router terminal:

```
root@sharksterrirory:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=59 time=5.613 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=59 time=7.039 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 5.613/6.326/7.039 ms



root@sharksterrirory:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.217.206): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.217.206: seq=0 ttl=56 time=4.763 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.206: seq=1 ttl=56 time=5.606 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 4.763/5.184/5.606 ms
root@sharksterrirory:~# 



root@sharksterrirory:~# wget http://google.com/
Connecting to google.com (172.217.5.206:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.217.5.206): Connection timed out
```

These commands are run logged in as my normal user, on my server running `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.

```
taylor@nas:~ > curl http://google.com/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection timed out



taylor@nas:~ > curl https://google.com/
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I'm not exactly sure what other relevant stuff I should be providing here, but I'm fairly confident in saying that my issue isn't IPv6 or DNS related, as a lot of my searches have led me towards. Given that the issue is happening at a router level, I've tried poking around with forwarding settings to make sure I wasn't doing something funky with port 80, but disabling all port forwarding except for my SSH on port 22 did not fix anything. Here's the output of `iptables -L` on my router:

```
root@sharksterrirory:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:telnet 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             nas                 tcp dpt:32400 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             sharksterrirory     tcp dpt:webcache 
lan2wan    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             nas                 tcp dpt:33919 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             nas                 udp dpt:33919 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             nas                 tcp dpt:32400 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             nas                 tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             nas                 udp dpt:ssh 
TRIGGER    0    --  anywhere             anywhere            TRIGGER type:in match:0 relate:0 
trigger_out  0    --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_10 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_3 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_4 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_5 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_6 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_7 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_8 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain advgrp_9 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_10 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_3 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_4 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_5 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_6 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_7 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_8 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain grp_9 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain lan2wan (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain logaccept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain logdrop (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       0    --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain logreject (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset 

Chain trigger_out (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

In addition, I use this startup script to open up port 8080 for remote web interface access over my domain. I could probably move these into an actual port forwarding rule, but I haven't.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1:8080
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Any insight or help would be appreciated, if you have any questions or need me to provide any other information, I can do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frontier "deactivated my service" due to lack of payment. I forgot to pay my bill and their idea of "deactivating service" is disabling incoming port 80. Either this is them being lazy, or it's somehow related to the fact that the fiber line isn't easily physically disconnected from their network.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I can't see anything in your firewall config that would do what you describe. You are talking about surfing the web from your house, right?  Not serving web pages from your house.  That would be different.

Connection timed out might indicate a firewall somewhere that's dropping packets on the floor (not rejecting them politely).

It's possible that someone upstream from you (like your ISP) is blocking you.  You may want to check spamhaus (or similar) to see if your IP is listed as a spam relay.

You can do ping and port 443, so that means everything is fine at the IP layer, so it does seem like a firewall problem.

Hope that helps
-Dylan

Comment: Yep - talking about surfing and not serving. I run a webserver on 80 that I have no issues serving for that matter, so it's just incoming 80 that doesn't work. I'll take a look at your suggestions, thanks for replying!

Comment: No results on spamhaus. I'll see about contacting Frontier (ugh).